# Alternatives to Heroku SSL Endpoint add-on

Tags: ssl, heroku, load-balancing, http-proxy

I'm looking for information on how to configure an HTTP load balancer or proxy server ([squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), [nginx](http://nginx.org/), [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/), etc.) to handle the SSL for my domain as an alternative to adding Heroku's [SSL Endpoint add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/ssl#endpoint) for $20/month.

The load balancer or proxy server would terminate the SSL connection and the last leg to the heroku server would be over http.

Comment: I don't have specifics, but it may be possible to use Amazon Web Services Elastic Load Balancer as such a SSL termination proxy. Latency should be low as Heroku runs on AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL is now included on all paid dynos. Thus, you pay only the certificate price.

https://blog.heroku.com/ssl-is-now-included-on-all-paid-dynos

Answer (score 2):

A new add-on was added a few short months ago called [Expedited SSL](https://addons.heroku.com/expeditedssl). This add-on provides you with both the registration of an SSL certificate along with the endpoint for serving it, whereas [SSL Endpoint](https://addons.heroku.com/ssl) is only the endpoint used to serve the SSL certificate you've already purchased from an SSL provider.

Comment: Thanks for this info. The single plan is $15.

Comment: This actually costs $35 because you have to pay the $20/month for the heroku ssl addon